# Android widget launch App and detect App Not found

Tags: android, widget, launching-application

I need a simple home Widget to launch an external app (ex: whatsapp).

In my MainActivity extends AppWidgetProvider (onUpdate) I use this code to create a pending intent and work great if the App is installed.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.whatsapp", "com.whatsapp.Main");
intent.setComponent(cn);

PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.activity_main);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageView, pending);

appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(currentWidgetId, views);
```

In the (onReceive) section i use this code for detect if the App is installed

```
 PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        List<ApplicationInfo> list = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);

        for (int aa = 0; aa < list.size(); aa++) {         
            if(list.get(aa).packageName.equals("com.whatsapp")){  
                 //app istalled
                noapp = 0;
            }
            else{
                //app not istalled
                noapp1 = 1;         
            }
        }         
    if(noapp1==1){
    Toast.makeText(context, "Whatsapp not installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

My problem is: 
This code detect if the App is not installed and display the Toast message but only the first time the widget is positioned in the home.
I need to display the message any time the imageview is touched if the App is not installed.
Please Help!

Karakuri I try to apply your suggestion.
This is my code in the main activity for attach the intent to the imageView:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppWidgetProvider{

public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
    for(int i=0; i<appWidgetIds.length; i++){
        int currentWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        Intent intent = new Intent(LaunchExternalAppReceiver.ACTION);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.activity_main);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageView, pendingIntent); 
        // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current App Widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(currentWidgetId, views);

    }      
  }   
}
```

And this the new class with BroadcastReceiver (I put inside my simpele code to check if the App is installed, just for test):

```
public class LaunchExternalAppReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public static final String ACTION = "control";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

    List<ApplicationInfo> list = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);

    for (int aa = 0; aa < list.size(); aa++) {  

        if(list.get(aa).packageName.equals("com.whatsapp")){  
            //app istalled

        }
        else{
            //app not istalled             
            Toast.makeText(context, "Whatsapp not installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }             
  }
}
```

This is my Manifest:

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" /><application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <receiver android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/mywidget" />
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name=".LaunchExternalAppReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="control" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative solution. Work greet but have an annoying little problem.
I attach an intent to the imageView in my main activity to launch a new class "control" in this class i check if the app is installed and launch her or send a message and offer a download button.
The problem is...if the app is installed the control class launch her but for a second appear the activity (control) screen before App open. Very annoying.
Someone can help me to make this final fix? Thanks.

In onUpdate (main activity):

```
    Intent controlIntent = new Intent(context, Control.class);          
    PendingIntent pendingc1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, controlIntent, 0);
    RemoteViews views1 = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.activity_main);
    views1.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageView, pendingc1);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(currentWidgetId, views1);
```

My new class (control):

```
public class Control extends Activity {
private TextView testo;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

    List<ApplicationInfo> list = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);

    for (int aa = 0; aa < list.size(); aa++) {

        if (list.get(aa).packageName.equals("com.whatsapp")) {
            // app istalled

            Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager()
                    .getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.whatsapp");
            startActivity(launchIntent);
            Control.this.finish();

        } else {
            setContentView(R.layout.control);
            // app not istalled
            testo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
            String text = "WhatsApp is Not Installed\nPlease Download Whatsapp from Play Store";
            testo.setText(text);

            Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exit);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Control.this.finish();
                }
            });

            Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.download);
            button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                            .parse("market://details?id=" + "com.whatsapp")));
                    Control.this.finish();
                }
            });

        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the ImageView click send a broadcast to a receiver in your app (using [`PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getBroadcast(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int))). In that receiver you can check if the external app is installed and launch it from there.

**EDIT**

Make a new BroadcastReceiver.

```
public class LaunchExternalAppReceiver extends BroadcastRecevier {
    public static final String ACTION = "some-unique-string-here";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // check if the external app is installed and launch it
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        try {
            pm.getApplicationInfo("com.whatsapp", 0); // throws if not found
            Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.whatsapp");
            if (intent != null) {
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            // package not found, you can show the Toast here
        }
    }
}
```

Add it to your AndroidManifest. Make sure the intent filter action matches the ACTION above.

```
<receiver android:name=".LaunchExternalAppReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="some-unique-string-here">
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Make your ImageView send a broadcast with this action instead of trying to launch the external app.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LaunchExternalAppReceiver.ACTION);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageView, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Thanks Karakury. I try this in my onUpdate section.... if (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0) != null){something to do} but the toast message still appearing when widget is open not on click. Can you explain more please.

Comment: Make the imageView send the broadcast intent instead of the intent that launches the other app.

Comment: This is over my code knowledge. Can you show me the code to do this? My code to attach the intent to the imageView is on top of this post.

Comment: @Daniel See my edits. I think you make things out to be harder than they are. Also, I discourage trying to launch another app's components by name; you never know when they might decide to update their app and change the name of their classes.

Comment: Thanks. I still have problems. I put my test code above. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Karakuri I put my code inside your Edit but disappear. Why? How I can post it?

Comment: @Daniel Edit your own post.

Comment: Ready. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: At this point you will have to try to narrow down which part is not working. Add some log statements in various places (`onUpdate` of the AppWidget provider, `onReceive` of the broadcast receiver, etc) and see what happens

Comment: Hi Karakuri I found a working alternative solution but I need to fix a little problem. Can you help me?